# Formating a list of mixed precision numbers

Tags: nombres, ponctuation

For a contrived example in en-US:

> 10, 10., 10.0, 1,000, and 1,000,000.

Which could mean:

- ten implying a countable amount
- ten with decimal point implying two significant digits
- ten with decimal and zero implying three significant digits
- one thousand using comma separator implying a countable amount
- one million using comma separator with ambiguous period which could be decimal or end of sentence

In fr-FR, would the same list be presented this way?

> 10, 10,, 10,0, 1 000, et 1 000 000.

In which case is the ambiguity at the end resolved? Is « ,, » ever allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lists of items containing commas, e.g. decimal numbers, you should use the semi-colon to avoid potential ambiguities. That said, the comma is not usually used without a decimal part. If you really wanted to specify “10 with two significant digits”, you can use 1,0⋅10¹. I don't think it's a real issue considering the narrow use case, though. The other numbers are fine.